# How do total rewards considered in reinforcement learning setting?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, intuition

I am new to reinforcement learning and struggling to understand the basic concept of how the reward is calculated. Let's say I have 10 users. At each time step, different news articles are recommended to different users. Reward signals are collected based on users' choice. I understand that the purpose is to maximise the total reward across all time steps. However, I am not really sure if the total reward is calculated for every single user or aggregated across 10 users? If it is across 10 users, I really cannot conceptualize how it works as each user will have different state at each time step.

I will appreciate very much if anyone can point me to some documents that clarify this. I am reading Sutton and Barto's book but still cannot figure this out.

Comment: Single user. Actions taken by single user constitutes a single play, an epoch. Actions of  multiple users are similar to repeated plays.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen: Thank you. This makes sense in the context of games. However, I am still confused when applying to recommend personalized news. I guess I need to think a bit more on this.